# ModalRight is not defined when using import function

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using webpack to bundle all my files together, but I'm having issues with trying to import the template component I created with default name, I keep getting `ModalRight is not defined`.

This is my App.js file that I'm referencing as the entry in the webpack.config.js

```
import Vue from '../../public-assets/js/vue/vue.js';
import ModalRight from '../../public-assets/js/vue/components/ModalRightSlide.vue';

window.Vue = Vue;
```

In my base file, I'm trying to call it like so:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

    },
    components: {
        ModalRight
    },
});
```

I've also tried in another page using `Vue.component('modal', ModalRight );` and `<modal></modal>` in the html, but I just get that error.

This is the **ModalRightSlide.vue** file

```
<template>
    <div>
        foobar
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

Comment: You need to import `ModalRight` into the "base file".

Comment: @thanksd The base file is a base.twig, it has the bundle.js file exported from webpack there already in a script src call. App.js is the entry, and the output is bundle.js.

Comment: Ah, that would be good information to include when describing your problem. The issue is that `ModalRight` is not defined in the `base.twig` file's scope. I would think that `Vue.component('modal', ModalRight );` in the `App.js` file would allow you include `<modal>` tags in your template, but twig templates are outside my scope of knowledge.

Comment: The thing is that it does, to make sure I tried `Vue.component('modal', { template: '<template><div>foobar</div></template>' })` and called the `<modal>` tag and it processed the tags, browser outputted foobar.

Comment: I was looking through the bundle.js, I changed the call from `import ModalRight from ...` to `import RightSlideModal from ...`, I even tried to make vue use it by calling `Vue.use(RightSlideModal) ` and even then, no references to `rightSlideModal` has been included in the bundle.js.. that's something. I do see 'foobar' in there though, and I know you can reference default names with .vue files.

Comment: If you register the component via `Vue.component('modal', ModalRight);`, that registers it globally. So `base.twig` still won't have a reference to `ModalRight`, but now you won't need to register it on the Vue instance via `components: { ModalRight }` anyways. You should be able to just use the `<modal>` tag (since your `foobar` example apparently works).

Comment: @thanksd Thank you for pointing that out, your answer led me to my solution. Since I'm not using nodeJS to to my app, I also needed to register the component when compiling via webpack.